# Optimal TextSize in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is there a method or do you know a possibility to find out the optimal text size in a text view? I think this could be very usefull if you have a changing text in a text view. This could also solve the Problem, that text on a small Screen is to big and the same text size is to small on a big Screen.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful tool in creating layouts that can fit all screen sizes is the attrs.xml.
Like drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc., you can customize the size of texts (and whatever attribute you want to customize for different screens) by creating a size-specific `values` folder.

Android also comes with built-in "recommended sizes". Try typing in

```
?android:attr/text
```

ctrl+space to see the list of recommended sizes for some of the most common elements that has text in it.

For TextViews you can also modify its `style` (not `textStyle`) and use some built-in values such as

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium
```